# How to edit and overwrite a Microsoft Word file in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I have an MS Word document on Google Drive.

I want to edit this file and save it (overwrite the file).

But every time it gets opened by Google Docs a new Google docs document is created. Is there a way to just edit and save it? I could not find a save item on the menu.

Comment: Related: [Editing Microsoft Word Documents in Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/43044/354)

Comment: See [my recently posted answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116281/88163) to the link posted by ale.

Comment: Nice, worked as expected! I upvoted your answer there.  Put this as an answer here.